# Google analytics data migration to Google Analytics for Firebase (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

As Google communicated recently Google Analytics for Mobile is going to sunset by next year. So i would like to know how to migrate existing Google analytics data to Google Analytics for Firebase (Firebase)?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot migrate your data from Google analytics to Firebase. The Best solution: Create firebase project & integrate Firebase sdk in your app and start tracking

For more details check this integration details for Android https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Is there any possibility by using BigQuery or any other backup / import tools ?

Comment: @santhosh have a look at scitylana - you can get a trial 14 day dump here. https://www.scitylana.com/trial

Comment: @Ramakrishnan: Are you working with either Google Analytics or Firebase teams? Is this an official answer from Google or you are just sharing your experience? I ask because I am facing the similar issue and would like to migrate my data from GA to Firebase.

Comment: Yes, it is true Vaibhav. Pls. migrate to firebase, else you will lose data GA SDK won't work properly from 1st Nov'19